# Valid way of accessing the address of the one-past-end element of a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, iterator, stdvector

I wanted to implement an iterator to use a custom class in a for range loop. The iterator access an internal `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr` of a Base class and returns a raw pointer to a child class.

This is what I came up with:

```
using upBase = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

class Test
{
   std::vector<upBase> list;
public:
   void Add(upBase&& i) { list.push_back(std::move(i)); }

   class iterator
   {
      upBase* ptr;
   public:
      iterator(upBase* p) : ptr(p)   {}
      bool         operator!=(const iterator& o) { return ptr != o.ptr; }
      iterator&    operator++()      { ++ptr; return *this; }
      Child&       operator*()       { return *(Child*)(*ptr).get(); }
      const Child& operator*() const { return *(Child*)(*ptr).get(); }

   };
   iterator begin() { return iterator(&list[0]); }
   iterator end()   { return iterator(&list[list.size()]); }
};
```

This works fine on the latest compilers (tested on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cT8cdE) with **GCC**, **Clang** and **MSVC**) but when using **Visual Studio 2015** the `end()` method throws a run-time exception:

```
 Debug assertion failed. C++ vector subscript out of range.
```

I search the internet for a proper way to access the address of the one-past-end element of a `std::vector`, but didn't find anything except complicated pointer arithmetic.

I finally came up with the following implementation for the `begin()` and `end()` methods:

```
iterator begin() { return iterator(&list.front()); }
iterator end()   { return iterator(&list.back() + 1); }
```

This doesn't complain at run-time. Is it the correct way to access the address of the one-past-end element of an `std::array` or `std::vector`?

If not, what would be the proper way?

Comment: How about `list.end()` ?

Comment: `list.end()` returns an iterator, while `list.back()` returns the last element. To convert an iterator to a pointer you first need to de-reference it, which trigger the same assertion failure in my experience.

Comment: `auto ChildView = list | ranges::view::transform([](auto& sptr] -> Child& { static_cast<Child&>(*sptr); });` with a range library (range-v3 or c++20 one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the proper way?

You are trying to re-invent the wheel. You do not need to implement the `class iterator` for your `Test`, as you could get the *begin* and *end* iterator from the `list` (i.e.  `std::vector<upBase>::begin` and  `std::vector<upBase>::end`)

Therefore just make them available via corresponding member functions in `Test` class:

```
class Test
{
    std::vector<upBase> list;
public:
    void Add(upBase&& i) { list.push_back(std::move(i)); }

    auto begin() /* const noexcept */ { return list.begin();  }
    auto end() /* const noexcept */ { return list.end(); }
};
```

**([See a demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/Yo6dza))**

---

Also note that the `auto` return is only possible since [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14). If the compiler does not support C++14, you can provide it as [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), as follows (assuming at least you have access to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)):

```
auto begin() -> decltype(list.begin()) { return list.begin();  }
auto end() ->  decltype(list.end())    { return list.end(); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I still need my custom iterator implementation which down-cast the **Base** element from the `std::vector` to a raw pointer to **Children**.

Comment: @Jean-JoëlBorter For what reason? Also here `*(Child*)(*ptr).get()`, you are doing a c-style cast, by which anything could happend. No matter the element in the `list` all are just `Child` or other `Child2`, it will cast to `Child`. This is not a good idea. Fix would be using `dynamic_cast`. That being said, why can't be the cast in the place where you use the iterator? for instance in the loop or where you use the iterator?

Comment: I totally agree that this isn't the best solution. It's a bit long to explain. This is legacy code (we are talking 30+ years old code) that I am currently refactoring. The code is using poorly designed c-style containers that doesn't support polymorphism that I am currently replacing by stl container.
The example I gave is a simplified version of the actual code. In order to not break everything I am doing this refactoring step by step. This solution is (hopefully) only temporary.

Comment: @Jean-JoëlBorter After having a look at the sample implementations, I found a way to go. You need `iterator end() { return iterator(list.data() + list.size()); }` there. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/3P5a3o). However, if possible I would suggest using `dynamic_cast` rather the c-style one. See [here for a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rsMzv8)